# Closing Service Now Tickets using Powershell

Tags: powershell, servicenow, ticket-system

Can anyone let us know if we can Close Service Now Tickets using Powershell Scripting.

Comment: This site is not an "get free work done" site.  What did you try?  Do you have code example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and if you go into the REST API Explorer in ServiceNow, it will even give you code examples.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but you should try out the excellent PowerShell module "ServiceNow" in the PowerShell Gallery.

It is super easy to setup, and will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Edit:
And here it is one GitHub: https://github.com/Sam-Martin/servicenow-powershell